# Standard JS GUI Control Libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework, gui-toolkit

As far as JS libraries go we have standards like jQuery for making our own tools, but are there very widely used libraries of reusable controls, to make up for all the standard GUI controls not supported in JTML? For instance sliders, tree controls, etc... searching online I can find 101 free versions of any given control but a well-established library would be better.

Comment: jQuery UI is a very popular one: http://jqueryui.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) most of the standard controls

[jQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) grid and tree controls

Answer (score 0):

My GUI toolkit of choice is Ext-JS. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/

Not free (for commercial purposes), but it's the most solid, complete, good looking Widget library out there. jQuery UI is very simple and doesn't have a well designed Component/Layout architecture.

There are a few other ones out there.